Is there a way to invalidate a `conversion_token`?
I am testing some functionality with the Pinterest Conversions endpoint and I have generated a conversion_token but I want to invalidate it as I have exposed it on the web.
Is there any way to do this?
I checked the configuration page on Pinterest but there were no options to invalidate tokens, only the option to create new ones, but apparently that does not invalidate older ones.
